# The probability that choosen ball is white is?

Tags: probability

### Question

> There are $10$ boxes each containing $6$ white and $7$ red balls. Two random
> boxes are chosen, one ball is drawn simultaneously at random
> from each and transferred to the other box. Now a box is again chosen
> from the $10$ boxes and a ball is chosen from it. Then the probability
> that this ball is white is

### My Approach

I tried solving it without using [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Let $E$ be the Event that Two random boxes are chosen, **one ball is drawn simultaneously at random from each and transferred to the other box**

While choosing the ball,there will be $3$ aspects-:

Case $1-:$ In Event $E$, white ball is transferred from  to other.

i.e Box 1 -:$\text{5 white and 7 red}$

Box 2 -:$\text{7 white and 7 red}$

Probability for case $1$ for Event E=$$\frac{6}{13} \times \frac{5}{12} +\frac{6}{13} \times \frac{7}{14}=\frac{11}{26}$$

Case $2-:$ In Event $E$, red ball is transferred from  to other.

i.e Box 1 -:$\text{6 white and 6 red}$

Box 2 -:$\text{6 white and 8 red}$

Probability for case $2$ for Event E=$$\frac{7}{13} \times \frac{6}{12} +\frac{7}{13} \times \frac{6}{14}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Case 3-: when the selected box is not participating in event $E =\frac{6}{13}$

Adding case $1,2,3$ gives me probability $>1$

I am confused here i am doing wrong!

please help.

Comment: Have you accounted for the probability of the case occurring itself? I mean, what is the probability Case $i$ occurs for each $i$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is way too complicated. Each of the $130$ balls has the same probability of being chosen, so the probability that it's white is $\frac{60}{130}=\frac6{13}$. The arrangement of the balls in boxes and the rearrangement in the first step are just distractions.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right.And yes i was making question complex which was too easy ..but sir can you please help me where i was doing wrong :)

Comment: @laura: Tony already pointed out one mistake in a comment -- you can't just add up the probabilities in the three cases, you need to multiply them with the probabilities for the cases to occur. Also, you seem to have $12$ and $14$ balls in the boxes after the transfer, whereas the problem states that one ball is taken from each selected box and transferred to the other, so there should still be $13$ balls per box after the transfer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see where you are going wrong, lets see all the possibilities of what happens when we first choose our $2$ boxes and then switch in the most *impractical* way. The key to seeing where you have gone wrong is the fact stated in other answers that:

> *"the exchange is even (one ball for one ball)"*

We have $10$ boxes and select $2$ at random. There are $4$ ways we could have switched the balls. Let us call the $2$ boxes chosen at random Box $1$ and Box $2$ and all the other boxes Box $N$

Case $1$: $\frac 14$ of the time, we switch a Red ball from Box $1$ to Box $2$ and a Red ball from Box $2$ to Box $1$.

Case $2$: $\frac 14$ of the time, we switch a White ball from Box $1$ to Box $2$ and a White ball from Box $2$ to Box $1$.

Case $3$: $\frac 14$ of the time, we switch a Red ball from Box $1$ to Box $2$ and a White ball from Box $2$ to Box $1$.

Case $4$: $\frac 14$ of the time, we switch a White ball from Box $1$ to Box $2$ and a Red ball from Box $2$ to Box $1$.

The $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ cases are trivial and nothing changes in the boxes.

The $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ cases are a little different. We end up with $7$ Whites and $6$ Reds in one box, and $5$ Whites and $8$ Reds in the other. That occurs for both cases.

Lets put it all together. Let $W$ be the event a white ball is chosen and assume the boxes have an **equal probability** of being chosen, that is the probability of choosing Box $1$ is $P(\text {Box} \ 1)=\frac 1{10}$, the probability of choosing Box $2$ is $P(\text {Box} \ 2)=\frac 1{10}$ and the probability of choosing neither of those i.e. Box $N$ is $P(\text {Box} \ N)=\frac 8{10}$. Then case by case we see:

$$P(W|\text {Case} \ 1)=P(\text {Box} \ 1)P(W|\text {Box} \ 1)+P(\text {Box} \ 2)P(W|\text {Box} \ 2)+P(\text {Box N})P(W|\text {Box N})$$
$$=\frac 1{10} \cdot \frac 6{13}+\frac 1{10} \cdot \frac 6{13}+\frac 8{10} \cdot \frac 6{13}= \frac 6{13}$$

$$P(W|\text {Case} \ 2)=P(\text {Box} \ 1)P(W|\text {Box} \ 1)+P(\text {Box} \ 2)P(W|\text {Box} \ 2)+P(\text {Box N})P(W|\text {Box N})$$
$$=\frac 1{10} \cdot \frac 6{13}+\frac 1{10} \cdot \frac 6{13}+\frac 8{10} \cdot \frac 6{13}= \frac 6{13}$$

Now lets see what happens in Cases $3$ and $4$:

$$P(W|\text {Case} \ 3)=P(\text {Box} \ 1)P(W|\text {Box} \ 1)+P(\text {Box} \ 2)P(W|\text {Box} \ 2)+P(\text {Box N})P(W|\text {Box N})$$
$$=\frac 1{10} \cdot \frac 5{13}+\frac 1{10} \cdot \frac 7{13}+\frac 8{10} \cdot \frac 6{13}= \frac 6{13}$$

$$P(W|\text {Case} \ 4)=P(\text {Box} \ 1)P(W|\text {Box} \ 1)+P(\text {Box} \ 2)P(W|\text {Box} \ 2)+P(\text {Box N})P(W|\text {Box N})$$
$$=\frac 1{10} \cdot \frac 7{13}+\frac 1{10} \cdot \frac 5{13}+\frac 8{10} \cdot \frac 6{13}= \frac 6{13}$$

Now putting it all together, using the Total Law of Probability:

$$P(W)=\sum_{i=1}^4 P(W|\text {Case} \ i)P(\text {Case} \ i)$$

$$=4(\frac 14 \cdot \frac 6{13})=\frac 6{13}$$

It appears that chancing the balls in the first round does absolutely nothing to the overall probability. In fact what you have missed, is that one ball is taken from **each** box initially, such that exactly the number of balls in each box remains the same.

Please let me know if I can clarify!

Comment: nice work ..(Y)

Comment: I'm really bored haha.

Answer (score 1):

There are 60 white balls among the 130 balls evenly distributed among the 10 boxes.   Since the exchange is even (one ball for one ball) it does not impact on the probability that you subsequently select one from the white balls.

$$\dfrac{60}{130}$$

---

*Alternatively:* In the second selection you either select a pristine box (with probability of 8/10) or one from the swapped pairs.   In the first case there are 6 white balls among the 13 balls in a pristine box.   In the second case there will be 5, 6, or 7 white balls among the 13 in the box with various probabilities.

To evaluate those probabilities:   There will be six white balls among the thirteen in the box if the balls exchanged were the same colour; there will be five white balls if one was exchanged for a black; or there will be seven white balls if a black was exchanged for an extra white.   Thus...

> $$\dfrac 8{10}\cdot\dfrac 6{13}+\dfrac 2{10}\cdot\dfrac{6\cdot(6^2+7^2)+(5+7)(6\cdot 7)}{13^3}$$

And that equals....

Comment: i am not getting $$\dfrac{6\cdot(6^2+7^2)+(5+7)(6\cdot 7)}{13^3}$$ part

Comment: @laura There will be six white balls among the thirteen in the box if the balls exchanged were the same colour; there will be five white balls if one was exchanged for a black; or there will be seven white balls if a black was exchanged for an extra white.